# Android Navigation Component navigate between graphs

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I've got two navigation graphs `nav_graph_red` and `nav_graph_blue` and two Activities `ActivityRed` and `ActivityBlue`.

In each navigation graph I have a flow with 3 Fragments. `redFragmentOne`,`redFragmentTwo`,`redFragmentThree` and `blueFragmentOne`,`blueFragmentTwo`,`blueFragmentThree`

Now I want to navigate from `ActivityRed` - `redFragmentOne` to the destination `blueFragmentTwo`.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

I tried it this way:

`Navigation.findNavController(ActivityBlue.newInstance(),R.id.host_navigation).navigate(R.id.blueFragmentTwo)`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Start Activity with intent and pass your destination as `Intent extra`.

```
 val blueIntent = Intent(requireActivity(), ActivityBlue::class.java)
 blueIntent.putExtra("navigationStartDestination", R.id.blueFragmentTwo)
 startActivity(blueIntent)
```

In `ActivityBlue` `onCreate` -> get the `intent extra` and define navigation graph

```
    val startDestination = intent.getIntExtra("navigationStartDestination", 0)

    val navHostFragment = nav_host_fragment_blue as NavHostFragment
    val inflater = navHostFragment.navController.navInflater
    val graph = inflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav_graph_blue)

    graph.startDestination = startDestination
    navHostFragment.navController.graph = graph
```

**Important!:**

Remove `navGraph="nav_graph_blue"` in your layout xml of the `ActivityBlue`

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_blue"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```